# What's a word that describes a person that easily gives up but is easily fired up too?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted to put in my presentation a word or phrase (either one will do) that describes a person that easily gives up but is easily fired up. Please help me.

Comment: erratic? inconsistent?

Comment: I'll go with "Inconsistent Mindset" thank you!

Comment: Bipolar.  But I wouldn't use it alone.  "Inconsistent Mindset" is not a good conclusion to this.  I wouldn't know what it means.  Someone who gets to highs and lows easily is emotional or flighty.

Comment: Please show us how you want to use it in a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can describe such as person with these:
easily motivated and demotivated